# Get data from each dynamically created EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Dynamically created EditTexts by Add button, and also I have assigned them unique ID's using setId(), Now what I want to do is to get values from the dynamically created EditTexts when the user taps a button, then store all of them as Sharedpreferences
This is the code
Thank you guys

ADDED CODES

```
    List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
Button btnSave, btnAdd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout layoutmain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutmain);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText ed = new EditText(ActivityOptions.this);
            ed.setId(ed.generateViewId());
            ed.setTag(allEds.size());
            ed.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layoutmain.addView(ed);
            // Add also to the allEds
            allEds.add(ed);

        }
    });

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        EditText ed = new EditText(ActivityOptions.this);
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("key" + ed.getTag().toString(), ed.getText().toString());


            for (EditText ed : allEds) {
                editor.putString("key" + ed.getTag().toString(), ed.getText().toString());
            }
            editor.commit();

        }

    });
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    ArrayList<String> allTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EditText e : allEds) {
        allTexts.add(e.getText().toString());
    }
    intent.putExtra("Text", (Serializable) allTexts);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating every new `EditText`, you generate ids by `setId()` but I don't see how these are going to be useful in your code.  
Instead set the tag of the `EditText` like this:

```
ed.setTag(allEds.size());
```

and add it to the list:

```
allEds.add(ed);
```

Now in each `EditText`'s tag you have stored its ordinal number (zero based) in the list and when you want to store its value in `SharedPreferences` you can do:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key" + et.getTag().toString(), ed.getText().toString());
editor.commit();
```

or by using a loop through all the items in the list:

```
for (EditText ed : allEds) {
    editor.putString("key" + et.getTag().toString(), ed.getText().toString());
}
editor.commit();
```

This way you stored all the text values of the EditTexts with keys like:

```
"key0", "key1", "key2",...
```

**Edit** 
Of you want to open another activity and pass the list to it:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    ArrayList<String> allTexts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EditText e : allEds) {
        allTexts.add(e.getText().toString())
    }
    intent.putExtra("Text", (Serializable) allTexts);
```

and in the other activity's `onCreate()`:

```
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Texts");
```

**Edit2**
Replace the code in `btnSave.setOnClickListener()` and the lines below, with this code:

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        for (EditText ed : allEds) {
            editor.putString("key" + ed.getTag().toString(), ed.getText().toString());
        }
        editor.commit();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        ArrayList<String> allTexts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (EditText e : allEds) {
            allTexts.add(e.getText().toString());
        }
        intent.putExtra("Text", (Serializable) allTexts);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to **add** the `EditText`'s to your list, so the save button will know about them and get their inputs.

After that you need to **specify** the save button (which I believe you did, but I cannot see a reference of it in your code).

Lastly just **implement** the logic for the save button in its `onClick()` (save in `SharedPreferences`).

```
List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
Button btnSave,btnAdd;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout layoutmain = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutmain);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                EditText ed = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                ed.setId(ed.generateViewId());
                ed.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                layoutmain.addView(ed);
                // Add also to the allEds
                allEds.add(ed);
            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

                for (EditText ed : allEds) {
                    editor.putString("saved_text_key", ed.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: mark as answer works bro .then how to pass the data to other activity as an ArrayList , or i will create new question ?

Comment: No you don't have to create another question

Comment: In order to pass an arraylist from one activity to the other, the type of the elements that are included in the arraylist must implement the `Parcelable` interface. After that create a `Bundle`, call `buncle.putParcellableArrayList(yourArrayList);`and then insert this bundle to your `Intent` that will start the other `Activity`, `intent.putExtras(yourBundle);`

Comment: any idea bro im new with Parcelable